using variables and/or async variables in stenciljs @component decorator
I'm not even sure if this is technically possible, let alone advisable, but thought I'd ask.
Is it possible to use variables or the result of functions in a stenciljs @Component decorator?
What I'm trying to do is use fetch to get a stylesheet from a cdn and then apply it to my component.  I know there are a couple of different ways to do this and just started wondering if this was even possible.  My guess is that it is not.  I'm thinking something like:
@Component( {
  tag: 'my-component',
  styles: await getMyStylesheet(),
  shadow: true
} )

where getMyStylesheet() is a function like:
public async getMyStylesheet(): Response<string> {
  const r = await fetch('https://my.cdn/file.css');
  const data = await r.text();
  return Promise.resolve(data ?? '');
}

Not even sure where that function would live. Not w/in my component's class or before the decorator.  Maybe in another file and imported????
As it is, I just use
@State() myCSS = '';
async componentWillLoad(): Promise<boolean> {
  const r = await fetch('https://my.cdn/file.css');
  const data = await r.text();
  this.myCSS = data ?? '';
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

render() {
  return (
    <style>{this.myCSS}</style>
  )
}

And that seems to work fine.  But I got curious and thought someone might know for sure.

I think the best approach would be to import your stylesheet from your index.html:
<head>
      <title>Your App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.cdn/file.css" />
</head>

In case you want it specific to your component or you don't have access to the root html you can add it this way in your render function:
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.cdn/file.css" />
        <p>Your component content goes here</p>
        </div>
    );
}


Oddly enough, some links will work and others won't. The part I didn't think was important was that the stylesheet sets up a lot of css variables in :HOST. That wasn't working for me with just a link. But some css files did, even on the same cdn. It was just weird.
